# WooCommerce wc_get_orders() caching

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a customer service area where the user can view orders from the front-end (if user has shop_manager role).

The orders are retrieved via the wc_get_orders function. I am attempting to sort these orders, via ajax from this page, but it seems that the order query is being cached? I can get one ajax sort to happen, but then that seems to be cached and can't be bypassed. I could be wrong, but I'm using basically the exact same setup with retrieving/sorting users, using WP_User_Query, and it will sort all day.

User orders endpoint

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_user-orders_endpoint', 'child_account_user_orders_endpoint_template' );
function child_account_user_orders_endpoint_template() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( $user_id <= 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    $args = array();
    $qvar = get_query_var( 'only_completed', 0 );
    $qvar = $qvar === 0 ? false : true;

    if ( $qvar === true ) {
        $args['status'] = array( 'wc-completed' );
        $args['only_completed'] = true;
    }

    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-user-orders.php', $args );
}
```

form-user-orders.php

```
...

// Orders statuses  
$statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();
unset( $statuses['wc-completed'], $statuses['wc-cancelled'] );

$orderby = 'date';
$order = 'DESC';

$default_args = array(
    'status' => array_keys( $statuses ),
    'limit' => $per_page,
    'paginate' => true,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'date_after' => $date,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
);

$args = ! empty( $args ) ? $args : null;
$args = ( null !== $args ) ? array_merge( $default_args, $args ) : $default_args;

$results = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Ajax to happen after clicking sort arrows

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: localized.ajax_url,
    data: {
        'action': 'user_management_sorting',
        'orderby': orderBy,
        'order': order,
        'only_completed': only_completed,
        'endpoint': shop_managers_form.managersForm.data( 'endpoint' )
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(response){
        shop_managers_form.managersForm.find( 'th.sortable' ).removeClass( 'sorted' );
        shop_managers_form.globalAjaxLoader.fadeIn(400);
    },
    complete: function(response){
        shop_managers_form.globalAjaxLoader.fadeOut(400);
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log( response );
        shop_managers_form.managersForm.find( '.response-area' ).html('').html( response.html );
        $( '#' + sortingHeader.attr( 'id' ) ).addClass( 'sorted' ).attr( 'data-order', shop_managers_form.next_order( order ) );
    }
});
```

Ajax action

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_user_management_sorting', 'child_user_management_sorting_response' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_user_management_sorting', 'child_user_management_sorting_response' );
function child_user_management_sorting_response() {
    ob_start();

    $orderby = $_POST['orderby'];
    $order = ! empty( $_POST['order'] ) ? $_POST['order'] : 'ASC';
    $only_completed = json_decode( $_POST['only_completed'] );

    $base = wc_get_endpoint_url( $_POST['endpoint'], '', get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ) );

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order,
        'from_ajax' => true,
        'base_url' => $base
    );

    if ( $only_completed === true ) {
        $args['status'] = array( 'wc-completed' );
        $args['only_completed'] = true;
    }

    if ( 'user-management' === $_POST['endpoint'] ) {
        $uses_meta = array( '_quickbooks_account_no', 'billing_company', 'authorized_user_status' );

        if ( in_array( $orderby, $uses_meta ) ) {
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $args['meta_key'] = $orderby;
        }
    }

    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-' . $_POST['endpoint'] . '.php', $args );
    
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    if ( ! empty( $html ) ) {
        $message = 'success';
    } else {
        $html = '';
        $message = 'failure';
    }

    echo json_encode( array(
        'message' => $message,
        'html' => $html
    ));

    wp_die();
}
```

I can make things semi-work by accessing these straight from the database via $wpdb->get_results() but I don't really want to figure out the whole raw sql for joining all the tables, then trying to access all the order info that I need this way..

Any ideas to get around the caching of wc_get_orders or alternative methods to accomplish this?

Comment: `order` and `orderby` are not doing the sorting correctly?

Comment: They do initially, but after the ajax response it doesn't change the order.